# std::tolower example from website not giving expected result

Tags: c++

I found an example of std::tolower, here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower

There's an example which, according to the website, should return `false` and `true` for this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>
 
int main()
{
    unsigned char c = '\xe5'; // letter å in ISO-8859-1
 
    std::cout << "islower(\'\\xe5\', default C locale) returned "
               << std::boolalpha << (bool)std::islower(c) << '\n';
 
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.iso88591");
    std::cout << "islower(\'\\xe5\', ISO-8859-1 locale) returned "
              << std::boolalpha << (bool)std::islower(c) << '\n';
 
}
```

But copy-pasting this bit in my own IDE gives me `false` and `false`, and so does the `run this code button` on the website itself.

EDIT:
So the locale is not being set properly. Using windows 10 with latest Jetbrains Rider.

This works:

```
    assert(std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"));
    //assert(std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.iso88591"));

    printf ("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL) );
```

But uncommenting the other locale will throw error.

Comment: Have you generated your system locale for `en_GB.iso88591` locale? Have you checked `setlocale` for failure?

Comment: Ah I'm on a windows 10 machine, so the error is in the locale then probably..I'll do some more googling about this

Comment: `std::setlocale` will return a `char *` representing the set locale, or `nullptr` if it could not set it. Try `assert(std::setlocale(...))`, and if your assertion fails, then you did not actually set the locale you wanted; this would explain the behaviour not being what you expected.

Comment: What is your platform? Besides if specific locale is installed on system, its name can be different on some systems (Windows).

Comment: On Windows try: `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1252");` - where `1252` is Windows code page for iso88591.

Comment: @MarekR CP1252 is **not** ISO 8895-1 but Windows-1252 which is a superset of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so problem is that on Windows locale names are not same as on Linux.

On Windows `iso88591` is represented by codepage `1252` so one of possible locale name is:`.1252`:

```cpp
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1252");
```

Not sure, but it is possible also `.Windows-1252` will do the job too.

You can also try [`boost.locale`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html) to try unify locale names (so it could work same on all platforms). Since this is C++ you need to use [std::tolower(std::locale)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower).

Comment: I think the cppref page should include a note stating that the example only applies to (presumably) POSIX systems.